# Can't figure out how to make a box with multiple images with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I've got three images that I'm trying to use for a box like this in my website:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/41/examplemg.png/

I am trying to do this with CSS and HTML but I have had no success on my own and have not found any article speaking on how to do this particularly.

I basically want it so that the mid_image repeats when I add content.

Comment: What do you mean when you say repeats when you add content? You want to repeat blocks of content with the image below it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeat a background-image, you set the CSS `background-repeat` attribute. In your case you should set it to `repeat-y`.

Something like this should do it:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="middle">Content here</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#top {
   background-image: url("sometopimage.png");
}
#middle {
   background-image: url("somemiddleimagetorepeat.png");
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#bottom {
   background-image: url("somebottomimage.png");
}
```

**Note** Omitted size attributes in the example, since we don't have any measures on your layout. You will however need to add `width` and `height` to your elements, to fit your layout.

Comment: You'd also have to define the sizes of `#top` and `#bottom` to match the size of the images, otherwise nothing would show.

Comment: @SenorAmor Sure, but for simplicity, since we don't have any measures to work with, I just added the CSS relevant for the background.

Comment: This one has worked, with one problem though; there is a white space between my mid and bottom images after adding <p>Test</p><p>Test</p>

Comment: Use firebug with fire fox to find where that white-space is coming from. I suspect it is a margin. Check bottom margin of middle, top margin of bottom and perhaps bottom margin of the p tags

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help guys! I figured out what the space was too, it was a CSS property I had for <p> tags that wasn't set correctly. It only had a margin of 0 for the top but it needed margin of 0 for the bottom as well

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top"><img src="top.jpg" height="" width="" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="middle">
        /* content here */
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"><img src="bottom.jpg" height="" width="" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middle { background: url('path/to/middle/image.jpg') repeat-y; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create the following html structure

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="top_image"></div>
  <div id="middle_image">
    text here
  </div>
  <div id="bottom_image"></div>
</div>
```

the assign the images as background images to their respective containers

Answer (score 0):

Other than set extra div and backgrounds this is how I would do it..

```
<div id="side_bar">
  <img src="top.jpg" alt="" class="top" />
  <div id="middle">
    text here
  </div>
  <img src="bottom.jpg" alt="" class="bottom" />
</div>
```

Then for the css I'd have

```
#side_bar {
   width: xxxpx;
}

#side_bar .top, #side_bar .bottom {
   display: block;
}

#middle {
  background: url(middle.jpg) repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: Oops yes I did, some things no matter how many times you look at them you just over look them.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents worth

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Add some content</div>
    <div id="bottomImg"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
   background-image: url("yourTopImage.png");
   background-position: left top;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   padding-top: /*Use Height of top image*/;
   width: /*Use Width Of Image*/   
 }

#content {
   background-image: url("yourRepeatingImage.png");
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#bottomImg{
   background-image: url("yourBottomImage.png");
   height: /*Use Height of Bottom image*/;
   width: /*Use Width Of Image*/   
 }
```

**The Lean <strike>CSS3</strike> CSS2.1 Version. Wont work in IE7 and below**

[:after browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Add some content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
   background-image: url("yourTopImage.png");
   background-position: left top;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   padding-top: /*Use Height of top image*/;
   width: /*Use Width Of Image*/   
 }

#content {
   background-image: url("yourRepeatingImage.png");
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#content:after{
   content: " ";
   display: block;
   background-image:url("yourBottomImage.png");
   height: /*Use Height of Bottom image*/;
   width: /*Use Width Of Image*/   
 }
```

**The Leaner <strike>CSS3</strike> CSS2.1 Version. Wont work in IE7 and below**

[:before/:after browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15)

HTML

```
    <div id="content">Add some content</div>
```

CSS

```
#content:before {
   content: url("yourTopImage.png");      
   height: /*Use Height of top image*/;
   width: /*Use Width Of Image*/   
 }

#content {
   background-image: url("yourRepeatingImage.png");
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#content:after{
   content: url("yourBottomImage.png");
   height: /*Use Height of Bottom image*/;
   width: /*Use Width Of Image*/   
 }
```

For an ugly as sin demo check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHvzU/)

From all the answers you can see there are many ways to skin this cat!